# Insert múltiplos com PDO php e MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach, sql-insert

Minha situação,

Um **formulário POST** com um input de texto e dois inputs radios.

Os inputs são nomeados respectivamente, **`nome[0]`** e **`tipo[0]`**.

Quando a pessoa adiciona mais campos do formulário coloquei um *.attr* para ficar **`nome[1]`** e **`tipo[1]`"** e sucessivamente conforme adiciona mais inputs.

- Fiz isso pra ter como transferir e preparar as informações deles via POST no meu arquivo de 'envio' php.
- Também me ajudou a manter os botões do radio no mesmo grupo em linhas diferentes.

No fim, gostaria de por esses registros na tabela do MySql em uma tabela, nos espaços **nome** e **tipo**.

Ficou assim o **PHP**

```js
<?php

include 'conexao.php';

$nome = $_POST['nome'];  // Aqui pega input text, o valor do name="nome[0]".

$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];  // Aqui pega do input radio, o valor do name="tipo[0]".


  if (is_array($nome)){
    if (is_array($tipo)){
       
       foreach($nome as $valornome) {
         foreach($tipo as $valortipo) {
        
$carimbo = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,tipo) VALUES (?,?)");

$carimbo->bindValue(1,$valornome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$carimbo->bindValue(2,$valortipo,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$carimbo->execute();
 

}}}}
```

Deu errado, mas...!

estou conseguindo armazenar somente os radios corretos, o nome é clonado pelo numero de inputs gerado :(

**Formulário**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o **MySql**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Andei vendo alguns em materiais sobre antes de enviar os dados ter de organizar as informações que pego dos vetores e depois enviar, mas não entendi muito bem dos textos que tive acesso...

Em suma, qual é o caminho para situações assim? Imaginando por exemplo até uma terceira opção de input... adoraria indicações de temas e de leituras.

Meu conhecimento é bem artificial, entendo um pouco do que está acontecendo mas não a profundidade da lógica dos códigos.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O insert saiu errado esse é o problema? o mais prático é deixar o name dos campos assim `name="nome[]"` na hora de recuperar são convertidos para um array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você está executando o `INSERT` o dobro de vezes, isso porque o primeiro `foreach` vai percorrer todos os nomes *(2 inputs = 2 `insert`)* e depois vai percorrer todos os "tipos" *(2 inputs = +2 `insert`)*.

Quando você trabalha com `input` dessa forma, você tem duas alternativas.

Forma 1: Utilizar apenas um `foreach` no `input` nomes, por exemplo, e através do `ID` do campo, capturar o valor do `input` *tipo*. Ex:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];  // Aqui pega input text, o valor do name="nome[0]".
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];  // Aqui pega do input radio, o valor do name="tipo[0]".


if (is_array($nome) && is_array($tipo)){
    foreach($nome as $key => $valornome) {
        $carimbo = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,tipo) VALUES (?,?)");

        $carimbo->bindValue(1, $valornome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $carimbo->bindValue(2, $tipo[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $carimbo->execute();
    }
}
```

Quando utilizamos o `foreach`, nós podemos utilizar 3 parâmetros: O array, Uma variável para capturar o índice do array e uma variável para capturar o valor do array.

Quando informo `$key => $valornome` eu quero dizer: "Capture o index do array e armazene na variável $key e capture e armazene o valor na variável $valornome".

Como `$_POST['nome']` e `$_POST['tipo']` tem a mesma quantidade de dados e segue os mesmos índices, eu posso, simplesmente, pegar o índice de um deles e acessar o valor de outro array. Ex:

`$key` sempre vai receber esses dados a cada passo (0, 1, 2, 3, 4...) pois os inputs vem da seguinte forma `nome[0]`, `nome[1]` etc. Assim eu posso utilizar o valor de `$key` para capturar os outros dados. Dessa forma `$tipo[0], $tipo[1], $tipo[2], $tipo[3], $tipo[4]...`

Forma 2: Você pode utilizar `inputs` como um "array multidimensional". Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="/index2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    Nome
                    <input type="text" name="data[0][nome]" value="Um" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Inteira
                    <input type="radio" name="data[0][tipo]" value="1" checked />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Meia
                    <input type="radio" name="data[0][tipo]" value="0" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    Nome
                    <input type="text" name="data[1][nome]" value="Dois" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Inteira
                    <input type="radio" name="data[1][tipo]" value="1" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Meia
                    <input type="radio" name="data[1][tipo]" value="0" checked />
                </label>
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

E no `PHP` basta utilizar um `foreach` e capturar os dados em um `array`. Ex:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data'])){
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $carimbo = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,tipo) VALUES (?,?)");

        $carimbo->bindValue(1, $value['nome'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $carimbo->bindValue(2, $value['tipo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $carimbo->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quanto as possibilidades em cima, sobre a mesma necessidade, tem alguma questão de performance? A primeira maneira que você mostrou eu não entendi como o segundo bindValue recebe a informação da [$key] relacionada com o `$tipo`. No próprio *if* já  verifica os dois ? tanto `$nome` e `$tipo`. Muito obrigado! deu certinho aqui, e bem prático a maneira de usar! (:

Comment: @Yemoja editei minha resposta. Adicionei uma breve explicação. Sobre performance, é basicamente a mesma coisa, só alteraria algo caso fossem muitos inputs. No `if` já verifico se ambas variáveis são arrays, caso uma dessas condições falhe, a verificação retorna false e o código abaixo é ignorado.

Answer (score 1):

Com esses foreachs encadeados o que acontece é para elemento em `$nome` o segundo foreach é executado e só depois volta o primeiro o que basicamente combina todos os valores. Por exemplo se cada array tem 4 elementos serão gerados 16 inserts quando deveriam ser apenas 4.

**[Exemplo combinação - ideone](https://ideone.com/WoNaqe)**

Para corrigir essa situação o primeiro passo é combinar os dois arrays com `array_map()` onde cada elemento de `$tipos` e `$nomes` serão combinados em pares em um novo array.

Com o array montado corretamente já pode passar ele direto no `execute()`.

```
$nomes = !empty($_POST['nome']) && is_array($_POST['nome']) ?  $_POST['nome'] : array();
$tipos = !empty($_POST['tipo']) && is_array($_POST['tipo']) ? $_POST['tipo'] : array(); 

$novo = array_map(function($nome, $tipo){ return array($nome, $tipo);}, $nomes, $tipos);

foreach($novo as $item){       
    $carimbo = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,tipo) VALUES (?,?)");
    if(!$carimbo->execute($item)){
        print_r($carimbo->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

Ou alternativamente:

```
$ingressos['nomesOK'] = !empty($_POST['nome']) && is_array($_POST['nome']);
$ingressos['tiposOK'] = !empty($_POST['tipo']) && is_array($_POST['tipo']);


if($ingressos['nomesOK'] && $ingressos['tiposOK']){
    $novo = array_map(function($nome, $tipo){ return array($nome, $tipo); }, $_POST['nome'], $_POST['tipo']);
    foreach($novo as $item){       
        $carimbo = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ingressos (nome,tipo) VALUES (?,?)");
        if(!$carimbo->execute($item)){
            print_r($carimbo->errorInfo());
        }
    } 
}
```

---

```
$nomes = array('fulano', 'joão', 'maria', 'george');
$tipos = array ('meia', 'inteira', 'meia', 'meia');
```

Dada as seguintes entradas, `array_map()` converte elas para o formato:

**[Exemplo array_map - ideone](https://ideone.com/vilzHG)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => fulano
            [1] => meia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => joão
            [1] => inteira
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => maria
            [1] => meia
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => george
            [1] => meia
        )

)
```

Comment: esses operadores ternários dos elementos `$nomes` e `$tipos` é uma maneira de comparar e identificar o contéudo da array? não sei se estou interpretando errado, mas o **:** diz que caso não realize a primeira operação, fica então valendo o array(); nesse caso, porque o uso do array() vazio ? - _ muito obrigado! esclarecedor sua resposta, me fez conhecer mais assuntos!! _

Comment: @Yemoja verifica se as variáveis não estão vazias (`empty()`) e se são arrays do contrário manda um array vaziou isso vai evitar entradas inválidas para o `array_map()` tem outras formas de também.